# Comparing multiple variables to database values

Tags: php

I am in the middle of making an inventory system for my work. I have a database created with a table called inventory and 20 columns inv1............inv20.

all of my information will be inserted in numeric values, for example I might have something like TV=1 or xbox=2

I am going to display these values in a 4x6 blocked table. I am using a template system so i have assigned each block to an inv column. Now the tricky part. I’m putting together some if statement that will display an image for the given value if equal to every row in the table will not have the same input so i need to compare x to y to see which image to produce. So as of now my page is full of if statements like this.

```
if($inv1 == 1){
$inv1 ="<img src="">";
}
if($inv1 == 2){
$inv1 ="<img src="">";
}
```

and so on all the way to 20. Now I would need to write this code 20 times per inventory slot which i do not want to do.

I guess my question is, is there a way to compare all inv columns  in a single if statement so I wouldn't have to write 20 if statements per item id?

```
if(inv1 or inv2 or inv3 == 1){
$inv1 = "<img src"">"
}
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can't use double quotes within double quotes; use single quotes instead.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel You can, you just have to escape them

Comment: thank you for your advice i completely missed that.

Comment: @peterm Yes, that's also an option. But the OP's code is not valid.

Comment: *a table called inventory and **20 columns inv1............inv20*** This smells like a very bad database design. Normalize you data from the beginning to be able to normally maintain and query your data

Comment: how would you design a database like this

Comment: *how would you design a database like this* If your columns inv1 - inv20 represent quantity for specific products (1 to 20) then you should have something like `product_id int, quantity decimal(19,3)` where  `product_id` is a FK to `products` table. If they represent something else explain it in detail, preferably in another question, and you can helped with the design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds like a job for switch:
http://www.tizag.com/phpT/switch.php

Comment: declare an array with inv1, inv2, etc.. then loop trought it with foreach, then use the switch statement